# Search Field on a Dialog - SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

Good Morning!

I an start working with SAPUI5

How can I set a Search field(sap.m.SearchField) on a Dialog?

Thank You

Comment: Please provide your code. StackOverflow is a platform used to help you get your code working and not to solve problems for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
new Dialog({
                title: 'Available Products',
                content: new List({
                    items: {
                        path: '/ProductCollection',
                        template: new StandardListItem({
                            title: "{Name}",
                            counter: "{Quantity}"
                        })
                    }
                }),
                beginButton: new Button({
                    text: 'Close',
                    press: function() {
                        that.pressDialog.close();
                    }
                }),
                subHeader: [
                    new sap.m.Bar({
                        contentMiddle: [
                            new sap.m.SearchField({
                                width: "100%",
                                value: "Search Term"
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            });
```